# Mapping very large GPS tracks using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gpx

I'm making a blog for an upcoming bicycle tour and I'd like to have a map showing my progress. I've searched for hours for an existing product or service and nothing even came close. I know it's possible because I've seen it done before (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19443192/billy/BillysRoute.html).

I will be recording each day's ride and getting a single .GPX file for each day. Ideally I'd like to be able to upload each day's .GPX to an online database like Google Drive or Dropbox and have the map automatically update including the new track. It would also be nice to be able to embed the map on my blog, but just linking to the map would also be fine.

So far I haven't even been able to find a method to place very many tracks on a single online map. Recently I tried dissecting the example I posted above to see how it was made and found that writing a fairly simple HTML/JavaScript might be the answer. I did my best reading through the Google Developer pages but having no coding experience I am pretty quickly overwhelmed.

TL;DR my questions are:

1) How was (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19443192/billy/BillysRoute.html) made and/or how can I make a similar one using several GPS tracks?
2) Is it possible to build an online map that displays several .GPX tracks drawn from a folder in Google Drive, Dropbox or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are asking is definitely possible. The question is where and how you want to do it. For example, for Wordpress-based blogs, there are plugins that allow you to easily do what you are asking for. https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/google-maps-gpx-viewer (and others) may be interesting for you. If you already have a blog then you should look at whether it has similar features you can use or enable.